# Create a SQL Server database automatically in a running C++ program

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I will like to ask if someone can point to me how to create a SQL Server database automatically in a running C++ program on visual studio. I also want to define the tables that will be created with the database. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to create a database from C#. if you want to define tables use the same code and replace str value with create table script.

```
String str;
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");

str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
    "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
    "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
    "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
    "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
    "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
    "SIZE = 1MB, " +
    "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
    "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
try 
{
    myConn.Open();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    myConn.Close();
}
}
```